# Cloudformation stack stuck in UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: aws-cloudformation

My cloudformation stack that has been normally getting updated in a couple minutes keeps getting stuck. ECS seems to get stuck sometimes waiting for a service to be healthy, but the service came up and was stable.

```
13:59:20 UTC-0500   UPDATE_COMPLETE AWS::ECS::Service   MyService
13:57:19 UTC-0500   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ECS::Service   MyService
13:57:14 UTC-0500   UPDATE_COMPLETE AWS::Lambda::Function   MyFunction
13:57:13 UTC-0500   UPDATE_COMPLETE AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition    MyTaskDefinition    
13:57:13 UTC-0500   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition    MyTaskDefinition    Resource creation Initiated
13:57:13 UTC-0500   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition    MyTaskDefinition    Requested update requires the creation of a new physical resource; hence creating one.
13:57:10 UTC-0500   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::Lambda::Function   MyFunction
13:57:10 UTC-0500   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName MyDomainName
13:57:05 UTC-0500   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  my-stack    User Initiated
```

Comment: Can't help debugging without knowing what your cloud formation stack template looks like.

Answer (score 13):

For people looking at this and not being able to progress. I was able to delete the stack by canceling the update with the cli.

```
aws --region REGION cloudformation cancel-update-stack --stack-name STACKNAME
```

then I was able to delete the the stack.

Comment: Tried this and got the following error: `CancelUpdateStack cannot be called from current stack status`

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be that a DomainName entity was being created with a cert in cloudfront, which takes up to 40 minutes. Was able to see it initializing in APIGW/Custom Domain Names.